# Problem while installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows

I am trying to install ubuntu 12.04 from usb .Everything is fine till I have to choose where to install it. It shows only the "replace windows" and "something else". I was expecting to see "install alongside windows" as I read on the forum. I see some suggestions to check if there are not up to 4 partitions on disk.  I am totally naive .

Below is the picture of my windows disk management. Please can you tell if it has 4 partitions. I see 3 partitions for disk0 and 1 for disk1.

Please help me find solution. I don't mind deleting the recovery partition if it will solve this problem. 
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You only had three partitions,try to create another ext4 partition as primary or logical using gparted partition editor through Ubuntu live-disk.

During the ubuntu installation choose the something else option and select the created ext4 partition to install Ubuntu.

Comment: if i do so, will it delete or harm windows?.

Comment: it doesn't harm your windows partition.

Comment: Hi Raj , how do i find the gpartition when i run live ubuntu from usb.

Comment: see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to install boot-repair on ubuntu live-cd.Try the 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

i also have 4 partition and I was install ubuntu along window 8 without any problem.
create a partition with the size more than 8GB (shrink Driver) do not format the partition just create it, restart your pc and install ubuntu.

follow the below link to install 
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmm.. isn't the system reserved partition suppose to be at the beginning of you hard disk? I mean, before the actual partition on which windows is installed. I think ubuntu concludes from that, that there isn't any other operating system installed on your hard disk rather than you or someone else (maybe the manufacture) created thise unusual partition table.

You have two choices here: If you bought you PC this way then you should keep the current table because that way you have the option of restoring and repairing the windows without using any installation disks. Which is more than just handy. But once you change anything it gets really difficult for you to restore back to that state.
But if you or the previous owner messed around here than there is not way around of manually creating an ext4 partition under the 'something else' option. But on the other hand: if ubuntu wasn't able to detect your windows partition before the installation it probably won't detect it while installing and updating the grub2 boot loader. Which means you won't be able to boot you windows at all.

I would suggest getting yourself some other (newer) version of ubuntu (13.10) and see if this one is able to detect the operating system.
If you have another (external) hard drive than also consider installing ubuntu on that one rather then messing around with your preconfigured OEM system.

Comment: i tried ubuntu 13.10 and it's the same. and i can't find gpartiton on 13.10 when i run it boot from usb.

Answer (score 0):

If you made it to the restart part of your ubuntu installation you already finished the setup. The problem is that your windows is preventing ubuntu from booting.

Next time don't rush and use the very first answer you get inside a forum. :-)

But for now you should be fine using EasyBCD (http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).

That'll help you. I guess :-P